# VBA, my code is recieving a type mismatch error

Tags: vba

The line that is recieving the error is:

```
If rngT1 = Range("A2:D2") Then
```

This is the full subroutine:

```
 Sub Copy_and_Paste_Other_Expenses()
     'Copy  Expense into the Payroll Journal

     Dim rngT1 As Range

        'Set the worksheet name and range appropriately
    Set rngT1 = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"), ActiveSheet.Range("D2").End(xlDown))




     'Paste other expense in  in payroll Journal

    If rngT1 = Range("A2:D2") Then

       rngT1.Copy

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Payroll Journal").Range("N43:Q43").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ElseIf rngT1 <> ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("dat.").Range("A2:D2") Then

      rngT1.Copy

     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Payroll Journal").Range("N43:Q46").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

     End If
    Rows("1:1").Select

    'Turn off Filter

    Selection.AutoFilter


End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure you can check if ranges equate each other. But you can do that with their addresses: `If rngT1.Address = Range("A2:D2").Address Then`

Comment: Unrelated, but drop the `.Select` and do `[ActiveSheet.]Rows("1:1").AutoFilter` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare Arrays like that (which is what you are implicitly doing as Range.Value is the default property of a range).

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to check that the two references refer to the same range you can do

`If Range1.Address = Range2.Address Then...`